# OpenGL window video capture problem

Tags: linux, opengl, screen-capture, qglwidget

Probably this is very easy but I can't find the right words for google to spit out what I need.
I have a custom derived QGLWidget and want to do some video capturing to show it to others.

The capturing works well for all other widgets (Buttons, Checkboxes, ...) but my GLWidget remains blank (to the normal user it is fully responsive). When I hover the mouse over it, then the rectangular area of the mouse is redrawn on the widget.

How can I tell my widget/the windowsystem to refresh the whole area when motion capturing?

Probably related to the same problem: I once made a session in TeamViewer where the same problem occurred.

**EDIT**

When I use the Qt Demo Hello GL and capture it there is the same problem.

**EDIT2**

I tried one of my GLUT Demos and they did not work either, 
also I read about problems recording opengl output but this was on windows machines.
Maybe there are also problems on linux?

Btw. I use xvidcap for the capturing.

Comment: looks like the buffer is not updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Btw. I use xvidcap for the capturing.

I'm not sure, but IIRC xvidcap uses the Xdamage extension to grab only, what programs report as being rendered new. OpenGL operations don't set the damage flag.

Personally I use ffmpeg for screencapturing under X11. Something along the lines

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r $FRAMERATE -s $WIDTHx$HEIGHT -i $DISPLAY+$XOFFSET,$YOFFSET -vcodec ... -b -y output_file
```

For example

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 18 -s 800x600 -i :0+0,0 -vcodec mjpeg out.avi
```

I found `mjpeg`, `ljpeg` or `x264 / fast lossless` codecs being well suited for this task.

Comment: Thank you for the ffmpeg advice, I will give it a try. However this will not solve the problem with TeamViewer. Do you know how I can set the damage flag for the GL Widget area?

Comment: @Nobody: As far as I can tell the only clean solution would be by modifying the Qt QGLWidget itself. Really, I must look at the source code to tell exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess as I have little experience with the GL widget specifically, but the first thing I would try would be to set the opaque paint event flag on your widget:

```
setAttribute( Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent )
```

Comment: I just wrote this in the widgets constructor but it did not change anything.